# disable the load on demand view in RadListView

Tags: nativescript

The default load on demand view in iOS appears with a white background, and the custom view using the `tkListLoadOnDemandTemplate` directive does work- but in both cases the view appears on half of the page: I use a `ListViewStaggeredLayout` with `spanCount` of 2, so it appears on the left or right side, depends on which item should be loaded next.
On android the default load on demand view looks ok, but also appears on the right or left, and once i set a custom view template, it doesn't appear at all.
Been trying to search in the [official](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/api/classes/radlistview.html), [iOS specific](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/ios/api/Classes/TKListView.html#//api/name/loadOnDemandView) and [Android specific](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/android/AndroidControlsDoc/com/telerik/widget/list/RadListView.html) docs, but couldn't find how to disable that view. 
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you create a Playground example where the issue can be reproduced?

Answer (score 1):

You want to disable load on demand? Just do not add any attribute regarding load on demand. It should disable (load on demand is disabled by default) the feature.

Comment: When I remove the template, it shows the default load on demand, which looks like `ActivityIndicator` https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-ui-widgets/activity-indicator

Comment: Can you share your code, so that I can have a look please? But before it, remove your platform and build your app again, and see if it works.